# data_generator.flow_from_directory() function reads 4 images out of 20

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, conv-neural-network

I have 20 images in ./data/pets/test path but function return only 4 out of all.

```
data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
validation_split=0.2,
rescale=1./255,
shear_range=0.2,
zoom_range=0.2,
horizontal_flip=True)

data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
validation_split=0.2,
rescale=1./255,
shear_range=0.2,
zoom_range=0.2,
horizontal_flip=True)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [keras document](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/)

```
image_gen_1 = data_generator_1.flow_from_directory('input1_dir',
                                shuffle=False,
                                class_mode=None)

image_gen_2 = data_generator_2.flow_from_directory('input2_dir',
                                shuffle=False,
                                class_mode=None)
```